# How to set data-src on img tag when it has src attr when using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, src, attr

I am facing a stupid problem. I am trying to make my images lazy load in my angular app, I have tried this 2 :

```
<img src="/img/blank.gif" data-src="{{appCtrl.img}}" >
<img src="/img/blank.gif" ng-attr-data-src="{{appCtrl.img}}" >
```

But they both set the `src` attr instead of `data-src`, am i missing someting here ? The only way to keep the `data-src` attr is not to have any `src` attr ??? This works as expected :

```
<img ng-attr-data-src="{{appCtrl.img}}" >
<img data-src="{{appCtrl.img}}" >
```

Why?
How to set `data-src` on img tag when it has `src` attr?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you-

You can do it using Jquery-

```
$("img").attr("data-src","appCtrl.img");
```

**JsFiddle-**

https://jsfiddle.net/codecore/2fqbbsst/

Comment: Tnx for trying but you are way off the problem here

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how angular plays in here, so i am not full sure how it plays into the problem; anyways `data` attributes are just loaded into the `dataset` on load, meaning if you have the `data-src` attribute a `src` property will be created in the `dataset` object for this element. That said, you can use this:

```
yourDOMElement.dataset.src = "{{appCtrl.img}}"
```

Comment: there are multiple ways to hack this outside Angular, instead of messing with dataset, i can simply set the src itself after angular finished rendering, but i am not looking for a hack

Comment: I guess i am not familiar enough with angular, i am sure someon else got the answer! Cheers.